# Get Spring ConfigurableApplicationContext runtime from a servlet

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I have the following code inside a method invoked by a jsf <h:commandButton>.
It gets the spring's ApplicationContext, meaning I can get a bean with this.

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ServletContext sc = (ServletContext) fc.getExternalContext().getContext();
ApplicationContext applicationContext = org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(sc);
```

**My question is** how to get the ConfigurableApplicationContext of the running spring instance.
I want to be able to call the .stop .start and .refresh methods.

Alternatively, If there is any other way to call them on the running instance please inform me !

*Note:* there is no main method in the application. It is a webApplication deployed on glassfish v2.1.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just cast to `ConfigurableApplicationContext`:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = 
    (ConfigurableApplicationContext) 
        WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(sc);
```

Comment: oh.. erm.. ok that worked! I feel like a virgin right now.. lol :)

Comment: @Stefanos Kalantzis well, it is not straightforward. You'd have to be familiar with the class hierarchy of spring, and with the fact that it has rather few concrete implementations, all of which implement that interface :)